# How do I build an Ionic 2 application in Codenvy

Tags: dockerfile, ionic2, codenvy

I am trying to build an Ionic version 2 application in codenvy and having got so far i have found myself stuck.

Using henyojess's docker (https://github.com/henyojess/codenvy-cli) as a sterting point I have made a couple of amendments upgrading NodeJS and installing the ionic@beta package

```
########## START DOCKER ##########

FROM henyojess/codenvy-cli
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs=0.10.29~dfsg-2 npm=1.4.21+ds-2 && \
sudo apt-get clean && \
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node && \
sudo npm cache clean -f && \
sudo npm install -g n && \
sudo n 4.3.1 && \s
sudo npm install -g ionic@beta

EXPOSE 8100 35729
ENV CODENVY_APP_PORT_8100_HTTP 8100
ENV CODENVY_APP_BIND_DIR /home/user/runtime
VOLUME ["/home/user/runtime"]
CMD env | grep CODENVY_PORT | awk '{ print "export " $1 }' >> /home/user/.bashrc && sleep 4h

########### END DOCKER ###########
```

I then go into the terminal, move into the apps root and serve up Ionic

```
cd runtimedir
ionic serve
```

This is where I run into some problems... I can browse to the application the normal way via the http://runnerp[x].codenvycorp.com:[y] url.

However When I go into the editor and edit '/home/user/runtime/app/pages/page1/page1.html' Ionic should then copy the changes to the www/ folder however i am getting the following trace in the terminal:

```
∆ Copying HTML                                              
√ Matching patterns: app/**/*.html
 ✗ Caught exception:
 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/home/user/runtime/www/build/pages/page1/page1.html'
    at Error (native)
HTML changed: www/build/pages/page1/page1.html
```

And the HTML isn't copied to www/build/pages/page1/page1.html as it says.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ran into almost similar problem. My application built and ionic serving fine, but I don't know which url to preview on a browser. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a permission issue. Did you check if you are executing as a root?